# Rails i18n Attributes Not Working via JSON API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

We have a RoR 4.2.5.1 API server and an AngularJS frontend.

I'm trying get the internationalism working and have setup my en.yml as so

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      nas:
        calledstationid: 'AP Mac'
    errors:
      models:
        nas:
          attributes:
            calledstationid:
              blank:
              invalid:
              taken: "has already been added to a location"
```

When I create 'nas' with a taken calledstationid, I'm expecting "AP Mac has already been added to a location".

Instead I get, "calledstationid..."

```
def create
  @nas = Nas.new(
    calledstationid: params[:box][:calledstationid]
  )
  respond_to do |format|
    if @nas.save
      format.json { render template: 'api/v1/boxes/show.json.jbuilder', status: 201 }
    else
      @errors = @nas.errors
      format.json { render template: 'api/v1/shared/index.json.jbuilder', status: 422 }
    end
  end
end
```

When I use the bang, I can see the calledstationid **is** replaced with ap mac in the logs.

So... my question is, why is the field name not being updated in the @nas.errors object? And how can I get this to work for multiple locales.

-- EDIT --

The error object:

```
@messages={:calledstationid=>["has already been added to a location"]}>
```

Comment: to get the value inside `@nas.errors` you need to use `.save` or `.valid?`. `.save!` will not populate it.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this. I was using ! to prove the value was correct.

Comment: so what is the issue ?

Comment: Read question? :my question is, why is the field name not being updated in the @nas.errors object? And how can I get this to work for multiple locales."

Comment: can you show what you are getting in the error object ?

Comment: and please remove the `.save!` from the post when you know what impacts it has. It distracts reader. That is why you got only one comment. We are thinking, you are not getting error message data because you used .`save!`

Comment: Sure thang, just updated q. Only included the bit that's being naughty

Comment: please replace `"has already been added to a location"` with `"%{attribute} has already been added to a location"`

Comment: Can you explain why the error object doesn't follow - I don't really want to go through 50,000 lines of code and replace each one when we've just implemented in yml locales

Comment: What you are getting is standard and correct output. And to get what you are looking for, without changing the yaml, need to use `ActiveModel::Errors#full_messages`..Because this method *prepends the attribute name to the error message*

Comment: Perfect, that sorts it. If you make into an answer, I'll accept. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to solve this.

**First:**

Edit your yaml file and replace the message with the below :

```
"%{attribute} has already been added to a location"
```

**Second:**

What you are getting is standard and correct output as per the current YAML configuration. But to get what you are looking for, without changing the YAML, need to use `ActiveModel::Errors#full_messages`.Because this method **prepends the attribute name to the error message**.

Comment: In my specific case I changed  nas.errors ---> nas.errors.full_messages